# Is it grammatical? "I'm happy to a high degree"?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

I want to use prepositional phrases instead of adverbs such as "very" and "so".

Is it grammatical to say "I'm happy to a high degree"

Comment: It’s perfectly grammatical, but not in the least idiomatic.

Comment: You are doing English wrong!  You should not "want to use prepositional phrases".  Instead you should want to communicate effectively.

Comment: You could possibly find examples of usage in 19th century literature, perhaps, but who says "I'm happy to a high degree" in the 21st century? This phrase will not make you sound more native or more erudite :)

Comment: The OP asked the question and has now vamoosed. So annoying...

Answer (score 0):

*happy to a high degree* is grammatical. However, it yields no results in Ngram.

To have *degree*, the closest we get to mean what you want is [happy to a **great** degree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy+to+a+*+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but even that is rare.  In fact its usage has gone almost extinct well before the year 1900.

I see no benefit in trying to learn or use such phrases, as commented.

Comment: to a degree is an idiom here and is usually not qualified.

Answer (score 0):

The OP says:
I want to use prepositional phrases instead of adverbs such as "very" and "so".

Answer:
We'd say:
**I'm happy or sad or despondent *to a degree***. That is an idiom. No adjective.

It means **somewhat** sad, happy or despondent.

He's annoyed to a degree.= He's somewhat annoyed.